# How to stop ZF2 from updating while running "composer update"?

Tags: php, composer-php

Here is my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "~2.5",
        "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "~5.0",
        "kbariotis/feedly-api": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

I want to run `composer update` but I don't want to update ZF2, just other dependencies.

Comment: Off topic from the question, but just a note to say that specifying "dev-master" is very rarely a good idea. The package you're using it for (kbariotis/feedly-api) does have numbered releases, so you should probably use those instead. Maybe "~1.0~ would be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want only a specific version to be installed see the documentation for `exact` If you specify the exact version you require it cannot attempt to upgrade your version of the package which `"~2.5"` suggests to composer is what you want to happen

So you could use for example

```
 "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.5.3",
        "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "~5.0",
        "kbariotis/feedly-api": "dev-master"
    }
```

> [See the documentation for `EXACT`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md)

With this you can run `composer update` and it should not attempt to upgrade the ZF Framework

Answer (score 0):

You need to run

```
composer update facebook/php-sdk-v4 kbariotis/feedly-api
```

instead.

Comment: This does not actually allow him to run `composer update` though does it which was what the question actually ask for.